# How to add getter to an existing object

Tags: javascript

I can have a getter in a JavaScript object like this:

```
var member = {
    firstName:"XYZ", 
    lastName:"zzz", 
    get fullName(){ return (this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName); }
}
```

I can even add more properties on the fly, like this:

```
member.isGuest = true;
```

But, is there any way we can add getters to an existing object? Something like this:

```
member.isGuest = get isGuest(){ return this.firstName == 'Guest'; }
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

try `defineProperty`

```
Object.defineProperty(member, 'isGuest', {
  get: function() { return this.firstName=='Guest' }
});
```

Comment: I believe one issue with the above solution is if you were to use Object.assign on the `member` object, the getter will not be copied as it would if it were set during object creation and is undefined.

https://jsfiddle.net/ygd20ws4/

Comment: @user1331784 this is because the created property is by default not enumerable. You can set enumerable key in description to true and Object.assign will copy the getter.

Comment: Actually with the enumerable key the getter will not be copied but the value at the time of copying.

Comment: @boorg So no way to make this 'work' in a sense that the 'getter' is copied over?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the new [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) this way:

```
Object.defineProperty(
    member, 
    'prop', 
    {
        get: function() { 
            return this.lastName.toUpperCase()
        }
    }
);
```

In the past you had to use [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) but now it has been deprecated.

Comment: You deserve an upvote for a FGITW failure. (You actually have more content!)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible not only with the above solutions, but also using the [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) operator.

```js
// Initialize x
var x = {
  x: 5
}

// Log x.x and x.y
console.log(x.x, x.y /* undefined */)

x = {
  ...x, // {...x} is the same as {x: x.x}
  
  // The getter
  get y() {
    return this.x
  }
}

// Log x.x and x.y
console.log(x.x, x.y /* Not undefined */)

// Set x.x to 1234
x.x = 1234

// Log x.x and x.y
console.log(x.x, x.y)
```

`...` is the spread operator, which "spreads" the contents of the object it is used on, hence the name. For example:

- `doSomething(...[1, 2, 3])` is the same as `doSomething(1, 2, 3)`
- `{ ...{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3} }` is the same as `{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }`

Comment: This actually shallow copies the existing object to a new object with an additional getter. Cleaner code. But doesn't work if you can't set the object you wish to add the getter to (for instance, a singleton/factory object)

Answer (score 3):

Moreover, you can add a custom getter and preserve the old value if it is not supposed to be calculated from other values, like in your example. To do so, create additional context layer using an anonimous function like this:

```
(function() {
    const oldValue = yourObject[targetProperty];
    let currentValue = oldValue;

    const getter = function() {
        return currentValue; // or do something before returning, like applying parseInt or whatever
    };
    const setter = function(newValue) {
        currentValue = newValue; // or add some customization as well
    };

    Object.defineProperty(yourObject, targetProperty, {
        get: getter,
        set: setter,
        enumerable: true, // depending on your needs
        configurable: true // depending on your needs
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the good old purposes of completeness, `Reflect.defineProperty` is also an option :). Note that `Object.defineProperty` and `Reflect.defineProperty` do not behave the same.

[MDN compares the two functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/Comparing_Reflect_and_Object_methods) (as well as all similar `Object` and `Reflect` methods):

| Method Name | `Object` | `Reflect` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `defineProperty()` | `Object.defineProperty()` returns the object that was passed to the function. Returns a `TypeError` if the property was not successfully defined on the object. | `Reflect.defineProperty()` returns `true` if the property was defined on the object and `false` if it was not. |

I prefer `Reflect` because I think boolean checks make more sense, but in general remember to error handle *if you think that there may be conflicts* (these should be infrequent when messing with object properties, unless one of your libraries is making similar, possibly conflicting changes).

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)
```

is the best solution like they say above.

what i want to add is, in order to copy `getter/setter` from object to other, you can use `Object.create()` & `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` like this:

```
let obj = {
 _value: 0,
}
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'value', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  get() {
    return this._value;
  },
  set(val) {
    this._value = val;
  }
})
const ObjCopy = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj),
 Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

This way, you will copy its `properties` + its `getters/setters` + its `prototype`

Answer (score -8):

You can only use get and set in a Class, It's mean that getter and setter method. but you can add a function to class:

```
member.isGuest = function isGuest(){ return this.firstName=='Guest';}

member.isGuest()
```

the get means that property can be read!
the set means that property can be write!
You can look it in book 《JavaScript:The.Definitive.Guide》6edition the 6 chapter！

Comment: This is definitively incorrect. You can use `get` and `set` on any anonymous object. Like `let obj = { get foo() { return 'foo' } }`. See the first example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get