# Javascript detect when style.display is used regardless of style change

Tags: javascript

Take the following html:

```
<div id="somediv" style="display:none;"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("somediv").style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

somediv is already hidden, some javascript runs, effectively doing nothing.  I need code that **detects when style.display has been used** in javascript, regardless of if style was changed or not.

I've tried [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationRecord):

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        alert(mutationRecord.target.id);
    });
});
observer.observe(document.getElementById("somediv"), { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

The above only triggers if there was a style change.  **I need it to trigger regardless if there was a style change or not.**

Comment: I think defining a [`setter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) for the display prop could work. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37808429/7362396 how to do this at runtime / to an existing object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... how do I do what your talking about? Object.defineProperty(style, 'display', { get: function() { alert('test'); } });

Comment: Have you tried Javascript Proxy?

Comment: I am definitely no expert in javascript by any means.  I looked at setter and I looked at Proxy, it looks like for both you have to create and use some custom object.  The problem with creating an object is I would have to rewrite a bunch of code.  If I could simply run code on 'style.display' use, then I would be finished.  Maybe theres not a way to do that?  I may have to tackle my problem a different way.  Thank you guys for your replies, good replies at that.

Answer (score 1):

So I did come up with an answer.  The way it works, is you grab every script tag, replace .style.display with your own function, and finally replace the DOM (which is the real trick):

```
//loop through <script> tags
$('script').each(function(){
        var scripthtml = $(this).html();
        if (scripthtml.indexOf('style.display') != -1){
            scripthtml = scripthtml.replace(/.style.display = 'none'/g, ".customdisplay('none')");
            scripthtml = scripthtml.replace(/.style.display = "none"/g, '.customdisplay("none")');
            scripthtml = scripthtml.replace(/.style.display ='none'/g, ".customdisplay('none')");
            scripthtml = scripthtml.replace(/.style.display ="none"/g, '.customdisplay("none")');
            scripthtml = scripthtml.replace(/.style.display='none'/g, ".customdisplay('none')");
            scripthtml = scripthtml.replace(/.style.display="none"/g, '.customdisplay("none")');
            $(this).replaceWith('<script>' + scripthtml + '</script>');
        }

});
```

Now here is my .style.display replacement function:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.customdisplay = function(showhide){
    //insert whatever code you want to execute
    this.style.display = showhide;
    alert('Success!  .style.display has been detected!');
};
```

**.replaceWith** is what actually changes the DOM.  The only thing this script doesn't do, is it **isn't able to look through included javascript files**.  Thank you all for your comments <3.

**UPDATE:**

When using **replaceWith** to add the script tag, ipad/iphone/ipod will execute the script tag a second time.  to prevent this double execution, you need to do this:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<script>if (1==0){' + scripthtml + '}</script>');
```

Your functions will be valid, but anything outside of the function will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you fully realise what you are asking for, but here is a short description of **closest options** I am aware of:

https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401

Basically, **MutationObserver** is the major improvement over past here that is closest to what you want and supported in modern browsers. **But the whole point of all this is it listens to changes.**

You are basically asking to detect even non-changes. I don't see you getting out of this problem other than:

**Writing a wrapper** for the ways you use to change this in code and then instead of calling the change call the wrapper. Simple, easy, requires refactoring all the calls in code.

**Overwriting** the actual functions that make a change. This saves you the refactor but you are playing with fire here. Rewriting a well-known function on a global level means a PERMANENT source of problems to you and all developers who work on the project.

**Polling** - in short calling over and over on some element to check properties. Not only it detects changes with a lag of 0 to the polling interval it also uses resources and if you want to monitor everything you will have to write a recursion that descends through the current DOM from the top to each node and check it. You are gonna kill the performance with this. How hard I can't tell but I suspect either polling interval will be long thus increasing the detection lag or your performance will dive down like a gray falcon.

I have 1 big question for you:

What led you to the state where you need this?
You basically want the ability for a program to detect when it is using a specific part of itself (be that as it is, a core part, one implemented by the browser).
This sounds similar to request: hey whenever I change or not change a value in any variable in my code I should be able to react to it.

I am not trying to sound like Naggin Nancy here but instead encourage you to question train of thought that led to this being something you need and figure out whether you want to sink further time into this, because I don't think you are getting that what you desire easily and I suspect it came to be due to poor design decisions in the past.

Comment: I do realize what I'm asking for.  You telling me nothing new on MuationObserver, see my original question.  To answer your question, we have a bunch of <select> lists.  Ipads ignore size= attribute and just show one line.  Customers can't stand that.  We have lots of code, and other programmers  don't like the idea of find/replace refactoring.  The goal is to not re-write code, and keep the same programming style.  And yes you are right, it was because of a bad design decision.  I appreciate your comments, I do need to practice my time management skills better...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I also read your solution, quite interesting, voting both the question and solution up since it appears there are valid reasons to need this.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the up votes!  Thanks for the comment, that gives me more confidence.  I was sure that when you posted your answer, I wasn't going to find any answers to this question on the internet (which of course I didn't hence this thread).  It would be cool if MutationObserver had an option to observe non-changes, but that would go against its own name (Mutation).  Have a good one good sir!