# How can I define resolver for object type in graphql-js?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have many graphql types in my application.

I use graphql-js to construct them.

```
// example
const TruckDriver: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'TruckDriver',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
})
```

Then I import such types in my different queries and mutations to define type of returned values.

But my resolvers don't return objects, they return instances of classes where fields information are in nested property 'info'. For example above resolver will return

```
{
   info: {
     id: '123'
   }
   ...
}
```

I wanted to add resolver in my types but I found that types don't have resolvers.

How can I easy implement logic of fields data parsing for my object types?

Comment: I have released a directive that does exactly this https://github.com/gajus/graphql-lazyloader

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify a resolver for each individual field, like this:

```
const TruckDriver: GraphQLObjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'TruckDriver',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString
      resolve: truck => truck.info.id
    },
  }),
})
```

or modify the resolvers for your Query and Mutation fields to return objects of the appropriate shape. Something like

```
async function resolve () {
  const trucks = await getTrucks()
  return trucks.map(truck => truck.info)
}
```

Comment: It is not a way. I want to do it in types. I have about 200 entities types and many relations between them. I want to find way to do it at level of type definition

Comment: The value returned in the response is determined at the field level, not the type level. There is no "easy" way to do what you're trying to do. You could extract the mapping logic into a higher-order function and wrap your resolvers with that if you want to make things more DRY, but at the end of the day, you're going to have to do the mapping because the shape returned in the resolver doesn't match the shape defined in your schema.

Comment: You could conceivably loop through a list of properties for each class and [programmatically define a getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808320/javascript-how-to-add-getter-to-an-existing-object) for each property that would pull it out of the `info`.